# Delete the response variable from a formula

Tags: r

Is there a simple way to delete the response variable from a formula? I've tried using `stats::update.formula`, like this:

```r
> update(y ~ x, ~ .)
y ~ x
```

But you can see that the above does not remove the response variable from the formula.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use NULL as the response.

```
update(y ~ x, NULL ~ .)
# ~x
```

Answer (score 3):

If the formula has a LHS then that LHS is stored in the second component so:

```
fo <- y ~ x
fo[-2]
## ~x
```

Note that `length(fo)` can distinguish between formulas with and without a LHS.

```
length(fo)
## [1] 3
length(fo[-2])
## [1] 2
```

so if we don't know if there is a LHS and want to remove it if there is one then:

```
if (length(fo) == 3) fo[-2] else fo
## ~x
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not terribly elegant, but you can do the following to delete the response variable:

```
formula(delete.response(terms(y ~ x)))
# ~x
```